# geometric realization of a simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

Let $K$ be a simplicial complex and let $|K|$ be the geometric realization of $K$. Suppose that the vertices ($0$-simplices) of $K$ are $v_0,v_1,\cdots,v_k$, $k$ finite. Let $\Delta^n$ be the standard $n$-simplex and let
$$
K_{n}= \text{Simplicial Map}(\Delta^n,K).
$$
Then
$$
K_n\cong\{f\in \text{Map}(\mathbb{Z}_{n+1},\mathbb{Z}_{k+1})\mid \text{  there exists a simplex  } \sigma\in K \text{ such that Im}f \text{ is the set of vertices of } \sigma\}. 
$$
Here we use $\mathbb{Z}_{n+1}$ to represent the set of all vertices of the standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$ and use $\mathbb{Z}_{k+1}$ to represent the set of all vertices of $K$. Analogous to the boundary map in singular homology, there is a boundary map
$$
\partial_n: \mathbb{Z} K_n\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}K_{n-1}. 
$$
We have that $\{K_n,\partial_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a simplicial complex.

**Question:**  Whether is the geometric realization of the simplicial complex $\{K_n,\partial_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ (weak) homotopy equivalent  to (or having same homology with) $|K|$?